# observeEvent not reacting to changes in reactiveValues

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to make an observeEvent react to changes in a reactiveValues object. Here, the reactiveValues "test_vals" contains the values of the 2 numeric inputs shown below.

Expected behaviour: observeEvent(test_vals,...) should execute whenever there is a change to either of the 2 numeric inputs, and "test_vals changed" should get printed to the console.

Actual behaviour: It doesn't execute at all.

Reprex below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("x", "x", 5),
  numericInput("y", "y", 10)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  test_vals <- reactiveValues(
    x = reactive(input$x),
    y = reactive(input$y)
  )
 
  observeEvent(test_vals, {
   
    print("test_vals changed")
  })
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you really need the `reactiveValues`? Can you just use `observeEvent(c(input$x, input$y), {print("test_vals changed")})`?

Comment: @MrFlick In this example I probably don't, but imagine I had 30 of those inputs, and multiple observeEvents (this is kind of the case in the app I'm building). What would I do in that case? It would be impractical to write things out the way you mentioned then. Thank you for the response btw.

Comment: @MrFlick Also, if the `observeEvent` is in another module, then I think the only way to handle it is to store the inputs in a `reactiveValues`, and then return that from the module. Do you know how to deal with a case like that?

Comment: Welcome. Please try to incorporate the above observations into your question, and then end by clearly stating what you wish to accomplish and how.